# Parse list into dictionaries within a dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, nested

dataset:

```
id = [1,2,3]
header = ['name','attack','defense']
stats = [['John',12,30], ['Amy',32,89], ['Lisa',45,21]]
```

I would like to obtain an output in the form of a nested dictionary. The keys of the outer dictionary will be the id and the values will be dictionaries the contain the other data. i.e.:

```
dict = {
    1: {'name': 'John', 'attack': 12, 'defense': 30}, 
    2: {'name': 'Amy', 'attack': 32, 'defense': 89},
    3: {'name': 'Lisa', 'attack': 45, 'defense': 21}
}
```

this is my current code:

```
dict = {}
for i in id:
    next_input = {}
    for index, h in enumerate (header):
        for sublist in stats:
            next_input[h] = sublist[index]
    dict[i] = next_input
```

It is not working because of the last for loop. the value of the inner dictionaries are just replacing themselves until the last sublist.

How can I correct this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop over the stats sublists; using the `enumerate()` option you picked, you'd have to add an index to the `id` loop and pick the right stats:

```
dict = {}
for id_index, i in enumerate(id):
    next_input = {}
    for h in enumerate (header):
        next_input[h] = sublist[id_index][index]
    dict[i] = next_input
```

However, you can use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up two lists for parallel iteration:

```
result = {i: dict(zip(header, stat)) for i, stat in zip(id, stats)}
```

This uses a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to build the outer mapping from `id` value to corresponding `stats` entry. The inner dictionary is simply build from the paired headers and statistics (`dict()` takes a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs).

Demo:

```
>>> id = [1,2,3]
>>> header = ['name','attack','defense']
>>> stats = [['John',12,30], ['Amy',32,89], ['Lisa',45,21]]
>>> {i: dict(zip(header, stat)) for i, stat in zip(id, stats)}
{1: {'attack': 12, 'defense': 30, 'name': 'John'}, 2: {'attack': 32, 'defense': 89, 'name': 'Amy'}, 3: {'attack': 45, 'defense': 21, 'name': 'Lisa'}}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
{1: {'attack': 12, 'defense': 30, 'name': 'John'},
 2: {'attack': 32, 'defense': 89, 'name': 'Amy'},
 3: {'attack': 45, 'defense': 21, 'name': 'Lisa'}}
```

Comment: Does `_` just mean last output in IDLE/REPL?

Comment: @NickA: yes, the Python REPL tracks the last expression statement result that is not `None` in that variable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am assuming that dict(zip(header, stats)) will give me an output of  {name: [John, 12, 30], attack:[Amy, 32,89], defense:[Lisa,45,21]}?

Comment: @MartijnPieters By the way, I am unable to run that code. I am facing an TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable. how can I troubleshoot that? Sorry, I have solve this problem.

Comment: @TimOng: I used `stat`, not `stats`; different variable. `stat` is bound to `['John', 12, 30]` first, so `zip(header, stat)` gives you `[('name', 'John'), ('attack', 12), ('defense', 30)]`, which is passed to `dict()`. You used `dict` in your code as a variable, so you are masking the built-in type. Use `del dict` to remove that name, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
id = [1,2,3]
header = ['name','attack','defense']
stats = [['John',12,30], ['Amy',32,89], ['Lisa',45,21]]

new_dict = {a:{d:c for c, d in zip(b, header)} for a, b in zip(id, stats)}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'attack': 12, 'defense': 30, 'name': 'John'}, 2: {'attack': 32, 'defense': 89, 'name': 'Amy'}, 3: {'attack': 45, 'defense': 21, 'name': 'Lisa'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `zip()` variation:

```
d = {}
for i,s in enumerate(stats):
    d[id[i]] = dict((zip(header, s)))

print(d)
```

The output:

```
{1: {'attack': 12, 'name': 'John', 'defense': 30}, 2: {'attack': 32, 'name': 'Amy', 'defense': 89}, 3: {'attack': 45, 'name': 'Lisa', 'defense': 21}}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[zip()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip)** and **[list comphersion](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php)**

```
>> dict(zip(id ,[dict(zip(header,item)) for item in stats]))

{1: {'attack': 12, 'defense': 30, 'name': 'John'}, 2: {'attack': 32, 'defense': 89, 'name': 'Amy'}, 3: {'attack': 45, 'defense': 21, 'name': 'Lisa'}}
```

first zip every item in stats with header

```
>>> [dict(zip(header,item)) for item in stats]

[{'attack': 12, 'defense': 30, 'name': 'John'}, {'attack': 32, 'defense': 89, 'name': 'Amy'}, {'attack': 45, 'defense': 21, 'name': 'Lisa'}]
```

second zip id with the output of first

```
>>> zip(id,[dict(zip(header,item)) for item in stats])

[(1, {'attack': 12, 'defense': 30, 'name': 'John'}), (2, {'attack': 32, 'defense': 89, 'name': 'Amy'}), (3, {'attack': 45, 'defense': 21, 'name': 'Lisa'})]
```